# Django load local json file

Tags: python, django, json

I have an ajax view:

```
def ajax_prices(request):
    data = {'data':'data'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

I want to test this with a local json file (prices.json). How can I import a local json file?

Local json file 'prices.json'

```
{"aaData": [
[1, "70.1700", "2008-12-29 11:23:00"],
[2, "70.2600", "2008-12-29 16:22:00"],
[3, "70.6500", "2008-12-30 11:30:00"],
[4, "70.8700", "2008-12-30 16:10:00"],
[5, "70.5500", "2009-01-02 11:09:00"],
[6, "70.6400", "2009-01-02 16:15:00"],
[7, "70.6500", "2009-01-05 11:17:00"]
]}
```

I can't do that with:

```
data = '/static/prices.json'
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the json module:

```
import json

json_data = open('/static/prices.json')   
data1 = json.load(json_data) # deserialises it
data2 = json.dumps(data1) # json formatted string

json_data.close()
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) for more info.

As Joe has said, it's a better practice to use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) or [factories](https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy) for your test data.

Comment: I get an error No such file or directory: '/static/portal/sample-dap.json'... the file is located at appfolder/static/app/prices.json

Comment: The path should be relative to the calling script or else specify a full path

Comment: Should be:
-> data2 = json.dumps(data) // json formatted string

Answer (score 9):

The trick here is to use python's built-in methods to `open` that file, read its contents and parse it using the `json` module

i.e.

```
import json

data = open('/static/prices.json').read() #opens the json file and saves the raw contents
jsonData = json.loads(data) #converts to a json structure
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use Django fixtures for this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs