# Django shell: Command to load test fixture data?

Tags: django, shell

Is there an easy way to load fixture data that I usually use in automated test runs in the interactive Django shell?

It might be awkward to have a mixture of model data that come from the database and others that come from a fixture. In my case, I have some read-only tables and wand to experiment with some data that I can discard afterwards.

I can probably load the fixture files like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498234/django-load-local-json-file), but that's a bit cumbersome for repeated use...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ilardm's answer points in the right direction, specifically what you want is:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('loaddata', 'fixture_name.json')
```

Edit: But the correct way to include fixtures in test cases is like this:

```
class TestThis(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['myfixture.json']

    def setUp(self):
        # Ready to test
```

Comment: In previous versions of django you could use:

`from django.core import management
from django.core.management.commands import loaddata
management.call_command('loaddata', 'test_data')`

Answer (score 5):

I expect [`./manage.py loaddata fixture_name.json`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I want the data available in a shell, i.e.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this link: http://testedwebdev.blogspot.ru/2012/05/django-shell-testing.html might help.